# Import React.Component doesn't worked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Yesterday, I've no problem with React... Today I started WebStorm for continue my project, and I can't React.Component is `unresolved variable`.

Check that screenshot if you understand :

[image]

Comment: Could you try with `import * as React from 'react'`? Ditto for `ReactDOM`?

Comment: @HoriaComan Same problem, I made a `npm install` 
I thought react is uninstall, but no all project are up to date...

Comment: There's too little information here I think for people to help. It could be a lot of stuff - removed `node_modules`, issues with the tooling you have, changes in WebStorm (if it does auto-updates) etc. Try a simpler example and see if that works to at least eliminate some issues.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Form extends Component {
    render() {

    }
}
```